# python:compare values with other values in dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, random, comparison

As per [this link](https://openhatch.org/wiki/Flash_card_challenge)

now i have to Randomly choose state as question and compare the answer with capital, if user provides right answer loop must exit.

I have a dictionary with

```
{'state': ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California'],
 'capital': ['Montgomery', 'Juneau', 'Phoenix', 'Little Rock']}
```

Comment: If you want help, you need to show the code you have written so far and explain what's not working. No-one will write the whole code for you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks to write a program without showing a genuine attempt to solve the problem on OPs side.

Comment: Note one of the goals of the exercise `practice breaking down a problem and solving it in Python from scratch`.

Comment: Sorry, i am learning python and Firstly, thanks for your support. i am unable to get the fetch the value(Alabama) once i can get the hint then i can go ahead and compare with capital value and display to user as Correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this might work (not tested), assumes that states and capitals are 1 to 1 and in the right order

```
import random
random_state = random.choice(your_dict.get('state')
index = your_dict.get('state').index(random_state)
answer = your_get_answer_method() #returns the answer, process if needed (lower ... etc)
if your_dict.get('capital')[index] == answer:
    #do some stuff here
```